# kotlin- i dont know how to use my adapter again with other view not in same list

Tags: android, kotlin

i have simple app that have tow fragment with tow recyclerview i need to use same adapter but with different layout not in same list as i find in all tot is it possible or i must copy it and reuse it ?

my adapter

```
class MainMarkAdapter constructor(private val activety: MainActivity, private var listOfData: ArrayList<MainMarkModling>,
                              val listener: ContentListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MainMarkAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun getItemCount(): Int = listOfData.size
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

    var inf = ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context).inflate(R.layout.min_mark_modling, parent, false))
    return inf
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(listOfData[position], listener,listOfData)
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bind(Data: MainMarkModling, listener: ContentListener,listOfData: ArrayList<MainMarkModling>) {
     val dataListin2 = listOfData[adapterPosition]

     var titlein = dataListin2.title

     itemView.textView.text = titlein

     itemView.setOnClickListener {
        listener.onItemClicked(Data)
     }
}
```

Comment: Having problems understanding what you're asking for, do you want the fragments to pass in the layouts? You can do that in the constructor.

Comment: But i cant pass the value as i need or show me please

Answer (score 0):

Switch layout at inflation.

```
// YourAdapter.kt
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    val layoutId = when(true) {
        true -> R.layout.for_true
        false -> R.layout.for_false
    }

    return LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layoutResId, parent, false)
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `YourAdapter.kt` also have the data for your condition?